# jq merge array of keys with array of values

Tags: json, jq

I have a json fragment with an array of keys and a separate array of values. Key 1 should match up to Value 1, etc. I'm trying to reformat with jq but not having much luck.

Original JSON:

```
{
  "result": {
    "event.KeyValues{}.Key": [
      "name",
      "gender",
      "employee",
      "email"
    ],
    "event.KeyValues{}.Value": [
      "tyler",
      "male",
      "yes",
      "tyler@nowhere.com"
    ],
    "foo": "1",
    "bar": "2"
  }
}
```

Desired Output:

```
{
    "name": "tyler",
    "gender": "male",
    "employee": "yes",
    "email": "tyler@nowhere.com"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `transpose` to pair keys and values. Then you can make an object out of each pair and add them together to get the desired structure.

```
.result
| [."event.KeyValues{}.Key", ."event.KeyValues{}.Value"]
| transpose
| map({(.[0]): .[1]})
| add
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/unCsQAXO7z)</sup>